# How to modify matrix multiplication to sum only positives or negatives values in R

Tags: r, matrix, cross-product

I want to do a matrix multiplication with a twist.

I have this matrix:

```
A <- matrix(c(1,-1,-1,0,-1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,-1,1,-1,0,0,-1,1,0,1,0,1,-1,-1,1,-1,1), nrow = 6, ncol = 5)

A
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    0    0    1
[2,]   -1    0    1   -1   -1
[3,]   -1    0   -1    1   -1
[4,]    0    1    1    0    1
[5,]   -1    0   -1    1   -1
[6,]    0    0    0    0    1
```

And I want to get two different matrices. The first matrix is this:

```
C
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0    0    0    2    0    1
[2,]    0    0    2    1    2    0
[3,]    0    2    0    0    4    0
[4,]    2    1    0    0    0    1
[5,]    0    2    4    0    0    0
[6,]    1    0    0    1    0    0
```

This "convergence matrix" is something like the multiplication of A for its transpose (in R is something like this `A%*%t(A)`), but with a little twist, during the sum to obtain each cell I only want de sum of the positives values. For example, for the cell C23 the regular sum would be:

> (-1)(-1) + (0)(0) + (1)(-1) + (-1)(1) + (-1)(-1) = 0

, but I only want the sum of the positive products, in this example the first [(-1)(-1)] and the last [(-1)(-1)] to obtain 2.

The second matrix is this:

```
D
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0    2    2    0    2    0
[2,]    2    0    2    1    2    1
[3,]    2    2    0    2    0    1
[4,]    0    1    2    0    2    0
[5,]    2    2    0    2    0    1
[6,]    0    1    1    0    1    0
```

This "divergence matrix" is similar to the previous one, with the difference that I only want to sum de absolute values of the negative values. For example, for the cell D23 the regular sum would be:

> (-1)(-1) + (0)(0) + (1)(-1) + (-1)(1) + (-1)(-1) = 0

, but I only want the sum of the absolute values of negative products, in this example the third abs [(1)(-1)] and the fourth abs[(-1)(-1)] to obtain 2.

I've been trying with apply, sweep and loops but I can't get it.
Thanks for your responses.

Comment: I think `C` is incorrect. Shouldn't `C[1,1]` be 3?

Comment: Alistaire, yes you're right, but I need the diagonal of the matrix with 0's, so I only change that with `diag(C) <- 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another take:

```
D <- A
D[D<0] = -1i*D[D<0]
D <- Im(tcrossprod(D))

C <- tcrossprod(A) + D
```

`A` is defined in the question.
Output:

```
> D
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0    2    2    0    2    0
[2,]    2    0    2    1    2    1
[3,]    2    2    0    2    0    1
[4,]    0    1    2    0    2    0
[5,]    2    2    0    2    0    1
[6,]    0    1    1    0    1    0
> C
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    3    0    0    2    0    1
[2,]    0    4    2    1    2    0
[3,]    0    2    4    0    4    0
[4,]    2    1    0    3    0    1
[5,]    0    2    4    0    4    0
[6,]    1    0    0    1    0    1
```

Comment: even easier, `D <- (tcrossprod(abs(A))-tcrossprod(A))/2; C <- tcrossprod(A) + D`

Answer (score 2):

It will be significantly less efficient, but you could break the matrix into a list of row vectors, which are easier to calculate with. Using `purrr`, which is handy for lists,

```r
library(purrr)

A <- matrix(c(1,-1,-1,0,-1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,-1,1,-1,0,0,-1,1,0,1,0,1,-1,-1,1,-1,1), 
            nrow = 6, ncol = 5)

C <- seq(nrow(A)) %>%    # generate a sequence of row indices
    map(~A[.x, ]) %>%   # subset matrix into a list of rows
    cross2(., .) %>%    # do a Cartesian join to get pairs of rows
    # calculate products, then subset before summing. Simplify to vector
    map_dbl(~{ij <- .x[[1]] * .x[[2]]; sum(ij[ij >= 0])}) %>% 
    matrix(nrow(A))    # reassemble to matrix

C
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#> [1,]    3    0    0    2    0    1
#> [2,]    0    4    2    1    2    0
#> [3,]    0    2    4    0    4    0
#> [4,]    2    1    0    3    0    1
#> [5,]    0    2    4    0    4    0
#> [6,]    1    0    0    1    0    1

# same except subsetting and `-` to make negatives positive
D <- seq(nrow(A)) %>% 
    map(~A[.x, ]) %>%
    cross2(., .) %>% 
    map_dbl(~{ij <- .x[[1]] * .x[[2]]; sum(-ij[ij <= 0])}) %>% 
    matrix(nrow(A))

D
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#> [1,]    0    2    2    0    2    0
#> [2,]    2    0    2    1    2    1
#> [3,]    2    2    0    2    0    1
#> [4,]    0    1    2    0    2    0
#> [5,]    2    2    0    2    0    1
#> [6,]    0    1    1    0    1    0
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a try in base R. So basically you follow the matrix cross-product approach but you try to manage the `sum` step manually:

```
f <- function(A, convergence=TRUE){
    sapply(seq_len(nrow(A)), function(i) {
        r <- t(matrix(A[i,],ncol(A),nrow(A)))*A
        if(convergence)
            r[r<0] <- 0
        else
            r[r>0] <- 0
        rowSums(abs(r))
    })
}

> f(A, convergence = TRUE)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    3    0    0    2    0    1
[2,]    0    4    2    1    2    0
[3,]    0    2    4    0    4    0
[4,]    2    1    0    3    0    1
[5,]    0    2    4    0    4    0
[6,]    1    0    0    1    0    1

> f(A, convergence = FALSE)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0    2    2    0    2    0
[2,]    2    0    2    1    2    1
[3,]    2    2    0    2    0    1
[4,]    0    1    2    0    2    0
[5,]    2    2    0    2    0    1
[6,]    0    1    1    0    1    0
```